# Django form que varia conforme outro form

Tags: python-3.x, django, jinja2

Como faço pra criar um form no django de um objeto e que o preço do objeto varie conforme o tamanho desse dele sem precisar atualizar a página.

#models.py

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    SIZE_OPTIONS = (
        ('30', 'Pequena'),
        ('35', 'Média'),
        ('40', 'Grande'),

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    flavor = models.ForeignKey(Flavor, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=SIZE_OPTIONS)
```

#form.py

```
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Pizza
    fields = ['flavor', 'size']
```

#template.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {{ form.as_ul }}
    {{ price }}
{% endblock %}
```

Quero que a pessoa selecione o tamanho e o preço atualize sozinho.

Comment: Idealmente você vai ter que fazer com Javascript para que o usuário tenha um _feedback_... E posteriormente, ao enviar o formulário, o Django calcularia este preço novamente.

Comment: Sem JavaScript não tem como fazer?

Comment: Sem Javascript você só pode se comunicar com o servidor enviando o formulário... A não ser que você pense em alguma gambiarra, mas não aconselho. Até posso pensar em algumas, mas prefiro não externalizar para o seu próprio bem... :D

Comment: Compartilha ai comigo, o objetivo é aprender bem o framework django. Estou empurrando javascript com a barriga por enquanto.

Comment: O que você poderia fazer é listar todas as combinações de sabor e tamanho com os preços e depois validar tudo no `clean` do formulário.
Mas como eu disse, seria melhor você calcular isso com Javascript só para mostrar para o cliente, e depois seu servidor calcula novamente para salvar no banco de dados.